# WINAPI serialize messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I am creating a window with the following 2 aims both of which are requird:

1. when person clicks outside of the window, the window is destroyed.
2. when a person clicks a button inside the window, we process the `WM_COMMAND` message, and then the window is destroyed.

To achieve both these goals, I looked and found there is a `WM_KILLFOCUS` message which is sent when the window looses focus.

I wrote destroy window code in the `WM_KILLFOCUS` handler, but then the button click message box does not come. I searched and found the destroy event is not serialized and hence it could be that it is being sent before the window button click could be caught. I have hence changed the code like below, where it also sends a `WM_COMMNAD` to kill the window.

```cpp
case WM_KILLFOCUS:
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, KILLTHEWIN, 0);// hope it serializes message
    break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (wp)
    {
        case KILLTHEWIN:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case BUTTON_CLICKED:
        default:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Hurray", L"Hurray MSG reveid", MB_OK);
            break;
    }
```

I see that when I click the button inside the window, the window is destroyed and the MessageBox "Hurray" is not received.

How can I ensure that the messages are processed before destroying the window?

**Update 1:** Minimal code as asked. Now  handling the WM_ACTIVATE message instead for handling WM_KILLFOCUS  .  Both the two aims are written above:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <map>
#include <commctrl.h>

#define KILLTHEWIN 10
#define  BUTTON_PRESS 11
LRESULT CALLBACK windowprocedure(HWND  hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
int  WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow)
{
 
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mywindowsclass";

    wc.lpfnWndProc = windowprocedure;

    // before creating window for a class we need to register that class 
    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
    {
        return -1; // registration failed
    }
 
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"mywindowsclass", L"My window", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE/*| WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW*/ /* check for no task bar*/,
        100, 100, 170, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    MSG msg{ 0 };
    
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        // translate  the messahe
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


// main window message handling 
LRESULT CALLBACK windowprocedure(HWND  hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    DWORD dwStyleOfStaticText = 0;
    HWND hBmp2 = NULL;
    WORD reason = 0;
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

        dwStyleOfStaticText = SS_NOTIFY | SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP /*| WS_BORDER */;
        hBmp2 = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Button1", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            5, 5 + 4 * 15, 100, 50,
            hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_PRESS, NULL, NULL);

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, 0);

        break;
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        reason = LOWORD(wp);
        if (reason == WA_ACTIVE)
        {
            //Activated by some method other than a mouse click (for example, by a call to the SetActiveWindow function or by use of the keyboard interface to select the window).
        }
        else if (reason == WA_CLICKACTIVE)
        {
            // activated by mouse click 
        }
        else if (reason == WA_INACTIVE)
        {
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, KILLTHEWIN, 0);
        }
        break;
    
    case WM_COMMAND: // when ever a menu is clicked 
        // WM_COMMAND has been received for which control handle and then kill it 
        switch (wp)
        {
        case KILLTHEWIN:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case BUTTON_PRESS:
            MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"button pressed", L"button pressed caption ", MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, KILLTHEWIN, 0);
        break;
    
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);// case other as default window procedure 
    }

    return (LRESULT)0;
}
```

The WM_ACTIVATE was handled above instead of the kill focus .
The two aims written above are really important . Still on pressing the button the MessageBox does not appear and window is killed .

I put it in debugger
one time the breakpoint hit the button message box but it still did not came . The other time the  breakpoint hit the WM_ACTIVATE  deactivate reason first .

Comment: So you destroy a window but expect that it receives a message after that?

Comment: `SendMessage` is not serialized when you send the message to a window on the same thread, instead the window procedure is called directly. If you want to serialize messages you can use `PostMessage`.

Comment: You should also consider the case the user switches to a different program or gets any kind of popup. Both cases, your window will lose focus.

Comment: @Devolus when i clicked a button aqt that time focus is not lost . it might have got lost because of message box from button click but i never see that comming as its blocking

Comment: @JonathanPotter PostMessage is also same behavior . My point 2 are not handeled. Button click should raiase Hurray messgae box first but didnt happen

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  the aim is that when focus is lost window should get destroyed . Hence i put it in WM_KILLFOCUS

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. We don't know, what `wp` is. Besides, you'll probably want to handle [`WM_ACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-activate) instead of `WM_KILLFOCUS`.

Comment: @IInspectable "*We don't know, what `wp` is*" - it is clearly the message's `wParam` parameter.

Comment: @rem What's *"clear"* about that? It's some symbol, but we neither know, where it's coming from, nor what type is it, nor what storage duration it has. It's not the conventional name used in any project templates, so what makes this so *"clear"* to you? And what point are you trying to make? Like, *"Hell, no, for the love of God, DO NOT provide a [mcve]!"*? Seriously?

Comment: Ekta: If that is your goal, then please [edit] your question to clarify that. Currently, it still says that when the user clicks outside the window.

Comment: Clicking on the button causes the main window to lose focus. (Focus is now on the button.) The main window therefore destroys itself before the button can respond to the click. You probably don't want the main window to destroy itself if it is losing focus to a child window. The `WM_ACTIVATE` message may be a better choice here.

Comment: @IInspectable i have added the code after removing other stuff .

Comment: IInspectable  &  @RaymondChen  I applied your WM_ACTIVATE suggestion but still the message box did not came .   The aim is that when I click outside the window the window is destroyed and when i click on a button , the message box comes and then the window is destroyed .

Comment: After debugging, I find that the window procedure continues to process ` WM_KILLFOCUS`  message although `MessageBox` which is in the same window procedure is blocked.

Comment: That's expected, since your window lost focus to the message box.

Comment: @RaymondChen so how can I achieve these two aims ? I want to kill it as soon as I click outside just like a pop up context menu gets destroyed  and just like a pop up menu when i click some item/window  , the main window should do some work & then get destroyed

Comment: You already explained your solution: "The main window should do some work and then get destroyed." So don't destroy while you're still doing work.

Comment: oh :) thanks!!  will try that  . I suppose  button WM_COMMAND will always reach before the WM_ACTIVATE lost focus.  I suppose it is guaranteed because lost focus was due to message box taking away the focus on itself   ..